# JavaScript for each with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, for-loop, foreach

I'm writing a Javascript application that gets some text from an xml file and displays it in a html table. Here's the code that i have for this task:

```
function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    //set servername
    var servername = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("servername");
    document.getElementById("server1").innerHTML =
    servername[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("server2").innerHTML =
    servername[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

How can i change this function to execute a variable number of servernames in the xml file?

Thank you very much for your help!

XML File:

```
<dashboard>
<server service="PRODUCTION">
    <servername>Testserver1</servername>
    <iis>OK</iis>
    <fim>OK</fim>
    <sql>OK</sql>
    <date>18.07.2017 11:50</date>
</server>
<server service="TEST">
    <servername>Testserver2</servername>
    <iis>OK</iis>
    <fim>OK</fim>
    <sql>OK</sql>
    <date>18.07.2017 11:50</date>
</server>
</dashboard>
```

Comment: What does your xml file look like?

Comment: foreach servername

Comment: added now the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it :

```
function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("servername");
    var i = 1;
    for(item of items) {
        document.getElementById("server" + i).innerHTML =
        item.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        i++;
    }
}
```

#### Demo

```js
var xmlString = '<dashboard>' +
'<server service="TEST">' +
    '<servername>Testserver1</servername>' +
    '<iis>OK</iis>' +
    '<fim>OK</fim>' +
    '<sql>OK</sql>' +
    '<date>19.05.2016 11:50</date>' +
'</server>' +
'<server service="TEST2">' +
    '<servername>Testserver2</servername>' +
    '<iis>OK</iis>' +
    '<fim>OK</fim>' +
    '<sql>OK</sql>' +
    '<date>18.07.2017 11:50</date>' +
'</server>' +
'<server service="TEST3">' +
    '<servername>Testserver3</servername>' +
    '<iis>NOK</iis>' +
    '<fim>NOK</fim>' +
    '<sql>OK</sql>' +
    '<date>11.02.2017 11:50</date>' +
'</server>' +
'</dashboard>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

function myFunction(xml) {
    // var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; -> We need to skip this line for our demo
    // That's because we're already passing an xmlDoc
    var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("servername");
    var i = 1;
    for(item of items) {
        document.getElementById("server" + i).innerHTML =
        item.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        i++;
    }
}

myFunction(xmlDoc);
```

```html
<div id="server1"></div>
<div id="server2"></div>
<div id="server3"></div>
```

(See also [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bwLvsyxL/2/))

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  //set servername
  var servername = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("servername");
  countServer = 0;
  for (let server of servername) {
    countServer += 1; //Here we generate the Html ID
    document.getElementById("server" + countServer).innerHTML =
      server.childNodes[0].nodeValue; //If serverX is not predefined you have to create it infront of it
  }
}
```

Simply loop trough the possible servers.

This code expects the html elements with the given ID to be predefined, if you doesn´t predefined them, you can generate them inside the loop too.